# Convert vertical (portrait) picture to horizontal (landscape), filling empty space around with blurred background

Tags: 7, media

How can I do this in Drupal 7?

[image: Convert vertical (portrait) picture to horizontal (landscape), filling empty space around with blurred background]

**Note:** Original question was [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/213179/13287).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created custom module called "[Blurred](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/jasom/2801585)". It can be described as "*post scale blurred background effect for images*".